# How to convert Matlab function with 'interp1' using two arrays and reference, to Python with 'interp1d'

Tags: python, matlab, interpolation

I used my Matlab code like this

```
Fas=[1.4, 1.4, 1.3]
Fvs=[1.5, 1.4, 1.3]

if S<=0.1
Fa=Fas(1);
Fv=Fvs(1);

elseif S<=0.2
Fa=interp1([0.1 0.2],[Fas(1) Fas(2)],S);
Fv=interp1([0.1 0.2],[Fvs(1) Fvs(2)],S);
end
```

then I want to convert it for Python with `interp1d`

so I wrote like this

```
if S<=0.1:
    Fa=Fas[0]
    Fv=Fvs[0]
elif S<=0.2:
    Fa=interp1.interp1d([0.1, 0.2],[Fas[0], Fas[1]],S)
    Fv=interp1.interp1d([0.1, 0.2],[Fvs[0], Fvs[1]],S)
```

### then I got the error message like this

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    [Spa_design,Fa,Fv,Sds,Sd1,To,Ts,Tl]=spe(site,S,T)
  File "/home/runner/timehistoryspectrumscale/Design_spectrum.py", line 28, in 
  Design_spectrum
    Fa=interp1.interp1d([0.1, 0.2],[Fas[0], Fas[1]],S)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site- 
  packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 444, in __init__
    raise NotImplementedError("%s is unsupported: Use fitpack "
  NotImplementedError: 0.176 is unsupported: Use fitpack routines for other 
  types.
```

---

I use the interpolate code with (and S=0.176)

```
   from scipy import interpolate as interp1
```

I'm a beginner, so I don't know the exact grammar of that module. but I want to find a way to interpolate using two arrays with reference value by `interp1d`.

Comment: Your Matlab code probably needs an else, and you need to (a) carefully read and then (b) post the *entire* error message

Comment: I'm sorry for invalid code. I miswrote an example.
Modify the last three lines as follows.

'''

elseif S<=0.2
    Fa=interp1([0.1 0.2],[Fas(1) Fas(2)],S);
    Fv=interp1([0.1 0.2],[Fvs(1) Fvs(2)],S);
end
'''

Comment: then I read the error message carefully then I found the type of variable is specified as a function. so I got the wanted result by adding the Fa=Fa(S) code, but it is questionable whether this is the best."

Comment: Please format the error as code

Answer (score 1):

scipy.interpolate.interp1d returns a function so you can call that function with an argument

```
from scipy import interpolate
Fas = np.array([1,2,3])
Fvs = np.array([1,2,3])

S = 0.15

if S<=0.1:
    Fa=Fas[0]
    Fv=Fvs[0]
elif S<=0.2:
    fa = interpolate.interp1d([0.1, 0.2] , [Fas[0], Fas[1]])
    Fa = fa(S)
    fv = interpolate.interp1d([0.1, 0.2] , [Fvs[0], Fvs[1]])
    Fv = fa(S)
```

I guess you are dealing with spectra. Just yesterday I wrote a [python code](https://github.com/kkocamaz/py_learning/blob/main/spectra/Untitled.ipynb) for spectra derivation from the ground motion data. Maybe it will be useful for you.